# How to export animation from blender to .3ds or .obj file without loosing animation?

Tags: animation, export

I have a model and I created a simple animation for that object, it is in a .blend file.

How do I export it to .3ds or .obj without loosing the animation?

Reply to Comment(I can't comment since I don't have 50 rep),

Okay, then is it possible to convert .blend with animation to .md2 with the animation? or .fbx with the animation to .md2 with the animation?

Comment: 3Ds and OBJ file formats don't support animation data, you cannot export motion data into any of those formats. Try FBX instead

Comment: Not sure what md2 format you mean, is this for the Quake IDTech2 engine? See https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/scenejs-creating-and-importing-3d-animations-md2-format